# iOS settings page items are jumbled

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have inherited a old iOS project that was created back in 2012 and is using some really old school techniques. I converted from 32 bit to 64 bit.

On the settings screens, the height of the settings items are not tall enough, causing the settings pages to look jumbled.

Any idea what is making this happen?

This page has no xib file, it's generated in code.

[image]

```
#import "GeneralSettings.h"

//preference keys
#define kGENERAL_ACCOUNT @"general_account"
#define kGENERAL_EXPAND_RESULTS @"general_expand_results"
#define kGENERAL_FINALS_ONLY @"general_finals_only"
#define kGENERAL_SEARCH_DAYS @"general_search_days"
#define kGENERAL_STARTUP @"general_startup"

@interface GeneralSettings ()

@end

@implementation GeneralSettings

+ (NSString *)accountNumber {
    return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] 
objectForKey:kGENERAL_ACCOUNT];
}

+ (BOOL)expandResults {
    NSString *expandResults = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] 
objectForKey:kGENERAL_EXPAND_RESULTS];
return expandResults ? [expandResults boolValue] : YES;
}

+ (BOOL)finalsOnly {
    return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] 
boolForKey:kGENERAL_FINALS_ONLY];
}

+ (NSInteger)numberOfDays {
    NSString *numberOfDays = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] 
objectForKey:kGENERAL_SEARCH_DAYS];

    if (numberOfDays) {
        if (([numberOfDays integerValue] != 90) || [Globals 
sharedInstance].isQA)  {
            return [numberOfDays integerValue];
        }

        //value of 90 lingering from QA session, reset to 15
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"15" 
forKey:kGENERAL_SEARCH_DAYS];

        return 15;
    }

    //default value
    return 7;
}

+ (NSInteger)showAtStartup {
    return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] 
integerForKey:kGENERAL_STARTUP];
}

+ (void)setAccountNumber:(NSString *)accountNumber {    
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [prefs setValue:accountNumber forKey:kGENERAL_ACCOUNT];
    [prefs synchronize];
}

+ (void)convert {
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if ([prefs objectForKey:@"finalsOnly"]) {
        BOOL value = [prefs boolForKey:@"finalsOnly"];

        [prefs removeObjectForKey:@"finalsOnly"];
        [prefs setBool:value forKey:kGENERAL_FINALS_ONLY];
        [prefs synchronize];
    }

    if ([prefs objectForKey:@"searchDays"]) {
        NSString *value = [prefs objectForKey:@"searchDays"];
        int index = 2;

        if ([value isEqualToString:@"1 Days"]) {
            index = 0;
        }
        else if ([value isEqualToString:@"3 Days"]) {
            index = 1;
        }
        else if ([value isEqualToString:@"15 Days"]) {
            index = 3;
        }

        [prefs removeObjectForKey:@"searchDays"];
        [prefs setInteger:index forKey:kGENERAL_SEARCH_DAYS];
        [prefs synchronize];
    }

    if ([prefs objectForKey:@"showAtStartup"]) {
        NSString *value = [prefs objectForKey:@"showAtStartup"];
        int index = 0;

        if ([value isEqualToString:@"Contacts"]) {
            index = 1;
        }
        else if ([value isEqualToString:@"Lookup Test"]) {
            index = 2;
        }

        [prefs removeObjectForKey:@"showAtStartup"];
        [prefs setInteger:index forKey:kGENERAL_STARTUP];
        [prefs synchronize];
    }
}

- (id)init {
    self = [super initWithTitle:xGeneralSettings withIconName:@"icon-
settings-general.png"];

    if (self) {
        //initialization
        Globals *globals = [Globals sharedInstance];
        SettingsSection *section = [self.sections objectAtIndex:0];

        //add account settings section
        SettingsSection *accountSection = [[[SettingsSection alloc] 
initWithTitle:xAccountSettings] autorelease];
        [self.sections addObject:accountSection];

        //create settings
        Setting *startupSetting = [[[Setting alloc] 
initWithKey:kGENERAL_STARTUP withTitle:xGeneralStartupTitle 
withType:pickerSetting] autorelease];
    SearchDaysSetting *searchDaysSetting = [[[SearchDaysSetting alloc] 
initWithKey:kGENERAL_SEARCH_DAYS withTitle:xGeneralSearchDaysTitle 
withType:pickerSetting] autorelease];
        Setting *finalsSetting = [[[Setting alloc] 
initWithKey:kGENERAL_FINALS_ONLY withTitle:xGeneralFinalsOnlyTitle 
withType:toggleSetting] autorelease];
        Setting *expandSetting = [[[Setting alloc] 
initWithKey:kGENERAL_EXPAND_RESULTS 
withTitle:xGeneralExpandResultsTitle withType:toggleSetting] autorelease];
        AccountSetting *accountSetting = [[[AccountSetting alloc] 
initWithKey:kGENERAL_ACCOUNT withTitle:xGeneralAccountTitle 
withType:pickerSetting] autorelease];

        //set setting parameters
        [startupSetting setPickerValuesFromString:xGeneralStartupValues 
withDefaultValue:0];
        [searchDaysSetting 
setPickerValuesFromString:xGeneralSearchDaysValues withDefaultValue:2];
        [finalsSetting setToggle:NO 
withSummary:xGeneralFinalsOnlySummary];
        [expandSetting setToggle:YES 
withSummary:xGeneralExpandResultsSummary];
        [accountSetting setPickerValues:[globals allAccounts] 
withDefaultValue:[globals defaultAccount]];

        if ([Globals sharedInstance].isQA) {
            [searchDaysSetting.pickerValues addObject:@"90 Days"];
        }

        //add settings to sections
        [section.settings addObject:startupSetting];
        [section.settings addObject:searchDaysSetting];
        [section.settings addObject:finalsSetting];
        [section.settings addObject:expandSetting];
        [accountSection.settings addObject:accountSetting];
    }

    return self;
}

@end

#pragma mark - AccountSetting class

@implementation AccountSetting

- (NSInteger)intValue {
    NSArray *picklist = self.pickerValues;
    NSString *value = [self stringValue];

    //return the index of our value
    for (int i = 0; i < picklist.count; i++) {
        if ([[picklist objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:value]) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return [super intValue];
}

- (void)setInteger:(NSInteger)index shouldSave:(BOOL)saveValue {
    NSArray *picklist = self.pickerValues;

    if ((index > -1) && (index < picklist.count)) {
        //save the value determined by this index
        [self setString:[picklist objectAtIndex:index] 
shouldSave:saveValue];
    }
}

@end

#pragma mark - AccountSetting class

@implementation SearchDaysSetting

- (NSInteger)intValue {
    //return the index of our value
    switch ([super intValue]) {
        case 1:
            return 0;
        case 3:
            return 1;
        case 7:
            return 2;
        case 15:
            return 3;
        case 90:
            return [self pickerValues].count - 1; //safe return of assumed index, which might not exist
    }

    return [[self defaultValue] integerValue];
}

- (void)setInteger:(NSInteger)index shouldSave:(BOOL)saveValue {
    NSInteger numberOfDays = 7;

    //save the value determined by this index
    switch (index) {
        case 0:
            numberOfDays = 1;
            break;
        case 1:
            numberOfDays = 3;
            break;
        case 2:
            numberOfDays = 7;
            break;
        case 3:
            numberOfDays = 15;
            break;
        case 4:
            numberOfDays = 90;
            break;
    }

    [super setInteger:numberOfDays shouldSave:saveValue];
}

@end
```

Comment: Did you try to set height for cells?

Comment: There is no tableView? If yes, show us the code, but I wouldn't be surprise if it were because of 32/64 bit issue.

Comment: What does the posted code have to do with the table view in the picture? Replace the posted code with code relevant to creating and populating the table view.

Comment: Agreed. You must have some code in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidLoad`. Posting your entire file would be more helpful, or there has to be a xib file connected which you don't know about

Comment: In your class file, where tableview delegate functions are declared add delegate method 'heightForRowAtIndexPath' and set the height of a cell.

Comment: This code is for storing settings, not for presenting them to user. Look for an appropriate view controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to look for UITableViewDataSource method:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 46;//here is height of cell
}
```

Or, add the following in viewDidLoad:

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 46;//here is height of cell
```

Comment: 1. If all rows are the same height, do not implement `heightForRowAtIndexPath`. That's very inefficient. 2. If you have a known, fixed height for all rows, don't use automatic dimension or estimated height. Simply set `rowHeight` to the fixed value. That's it. 3. This answer is premature until the question is properly updated with relevant code.